# How to change the frame that is shown as video thumbnail in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, video, thumbnails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use later frame for video thumbnail in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/54989/use-later-frame-for-video-thumbnail-in-windows-7)

I have many videos whose thumbnails are black (title part with black background). It makes video thumbnails almost useless.

How to make it show a later frame as thumbnail? I googled a lot but couldn't find an answer :(

Comment: I marked this as dupe but on second look the answer to the first time this was asked has a link that may be incorrect (plus the original is pretty old).