# Custom time offset for video thumbnails in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, video, windows-explorer, thumbnails

Windows Explorer uses the frame on a certain point of time for video thumbnails. Obviously it's not the first frame as this would often be plain black.

And as Windows advances from Vista, 7, 8 to 10, this time offset also seems to have changed. So I'm thinking there could potentially be a registry value somewhere.

**Is there a way to manually define this point in time?** - Setting the frame that is being used to be the frame at **00:05:00**, for example? *What I'm not looking for is a way to use a custom image.*

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/54989/use-later-frame-for-video-thumbnail-in-windows-7) provides a link to a tool that looks primising, but is 7 years old and not up-to-date. So therefore it is **not a duplicate.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, I stumbled upon a tool, called **Icaros 3.0.0.0**. I'm not sure where the official download page is, so I'm not linking it.

However, this seems to serve exactly the intended purpose: Defining either a start time *or* percentage of the full length where the thumbnail should be taken from. And Windows Explorer will display this thumbnail.

You can find the original source and download mirrors of Icaros here:
http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/icaros.html

Otherwise search for "Icaros Shark007"