# Windows 10: Set video thumbnails to specific frame or manage default offset

Tags: windows-10, video, thumbnails

SOLUTION FOUND: If anyone ever stumble over the similar problem -- Icaros is the solution. majorgeeks.com/files/details/icaros.html

I've got bunch of similar video files with preview thumbnails that are quite uninformative, since they begin in very similar way. I need:

A) To change default time offset for thumbnail generation to at least one minute (or 5-10% of video)

or

B) Some tool to manually select frame which will be used as thumbnail

Using another file explorer is an option but not the best one.

I've done some research, but I didn't quite understand how does Windows specify time offset and create a thumbnail. I'm even considering writing a script/app to solve this problem, if you would kindly tell me where I can find this info.

Some similar questions, yet not yielding the solution

This one is pretty close, but has no actual answers:
[Set shorter video file thumbnail generation timeout in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/1324465/set-shorter-video-file-thumbnail-generation-timeout-in-windows-7)

Doesn't work for Windows 10:
[Use later frame for video thumbnail in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/54989/use-later-frame-for-video-thumbnail-in-windows-7)

Comment: UPD: found a software to manually set any image as a thumbnail, but it isn't what I actually need. While choosing manually the offset for each video file is long yet acceptable, making the image from thumbnail manually each time is too much.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrZMFFUsnzU

Comment: Well, lets assume this is one of the yet unsolved problems for Win10. At least, for now. The best I was able to find is https://github.com/Martchus/tageditor/releases
Still, it needs feature to create thumbnail right from the video by offset, without manually exporting a frame. It's opensource, so maybe one day I'll fork it.
Unbelievable.

Comment: UPD: Solution found. If anyone ever stumble over the similar problem -- Icaros is the solution.
https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/icaros.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use later frame for video thumbnail in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/54989/use-later-frame-for-video-thumbnail-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 3):

Hello from 1y and 9month later.
I found a solution here :

https://www.bannerbear.com/blog/how-to-set-a-custom-thumbnail-for-a-video-file-using-ffmpeg/#pre-requisite

Basically I do:

1. `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:19 -i "videoName.mp4" -frames:v 1 thumbnail.png`

It take the frame of the video at 00h00min19s then output an image named "thumbnail".

2. `ffmpeg -i "videoName.mp4" -i thumbnail.png -map 1 -map 0 -c copy -disposition:0 attached_pic "videoNameName.mp4"`

It **copy**s the video and use the "thumbnail.png" as thumbnail. "videoNameName" is the output name, make sure it's different to avoid replacing other thing.